# How to write byte or stream to Apache Camel FTP to transfer file

Tags: java, stream, byte, filestream, camel-ftp

In my code currently, I get data from the database and then I write a file out of the data. I have this kind of camel route and working solution:-

```
private static final String INPUT_FILE_DIRECTORY_URI = "file:" + System.getProperty("user.home")
        + "/data/cdr/?noop=false";

private static final String SFTP_SERVER = "sftp://" +System.getProperty("user.name")
        + "@sftp_server_url/data/cdr/?privateKeyFile=~/.ssh/id_rsa&passiveMode=true";

from(INPUT_FILE_DIRECTORY_URI)
            .streamCaching()
            .log("Sending file to local sftp")
            .to(SFTP_SERVER);
```

I don't want to write a file in the local disk. Instead, I want to write file data directly to the SFTP server. I don't know how to do it? But I imagine it should be possible to do it. Can you tell me is it possible? If yes, how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem in another way. It is more suitable for my particular problem.

```
             byte[] csvData = csvStringBuilder.toString().getBytes();
             Routes.withProducer(producer)
                    .withHeader(Exchange.FILE_NAME, myCsvFile.csv)
                    .withBody(csvData)
                    .to(SFTP_SERVER).request(byte[].class);
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use streamCaching unless you really using it. It store your file in memory, use it if you need to consume multiples times your input.

You can use [Jpa component](http://camel.apache.org/jpa.html) or a custom bean getting your data. Load it from database and then send it to your ftp server.

With Jpa :

```
@Entity 
@NamedQuery(name = "data", query = "select x from Data x where x.id = 1") 
public class Data { ... }
```

After that you can define a consumer uri like this one:

```
from("jpa://org.examples.Data?consumer.namedQuery=data")
.to("SFTP_SERVER");
```

EDIT : to convert a list to csv and send it to ftp :

```
from("jpa://org.examples.Data?consumer.namedQuery=data")
.marshal()
.csv()
.to("sftp://" +System.getProperty("user.name") + 
"@sftp_server_url/data/cdr/myFile.csv?" +"privateKeyFile=~/.ssh/id_rsa&passiveMode=true");
```

See [CSV component](http://camel.apache.org/csv.html) who convert a list to a csv file.

Comment: Thanks. But actually, I don't get my data from the database. I get it as a list from another source. There is no camel component for it. So the question should be how do I write a list to the sftp endpoint? The list data should be saved as CSV file at sftp.

Comment: You need to marshall your list with the camel csv component and then send it to your ftp server.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible :) To do this send the file inputStream in a camel DIRECT component and in the associated route make the copy to FTP. I use this case, to upload a file and directly copy it to ftp with from(directInputStreamName).to(yourFtpUri). This is an sample code :

**Your service**

```
@Service
public class FileService {
  @Produce(uri = PfnumDownloadConstants.CAMEL_DIRECT_UPLOAD)
  private ProducerTemplate producer;

  public void sendFileToFtp(File fileToSend, String ftpDestinationUri) throws IOException {
    Map<String, Object> headers = new HashMap<>();
    //In this variable you can init the ftp destination uri or you can hard code it in route
    headers.put("destinationUri", ftpDestinationUri);
    //set filename to name your file in ftp
    headers.put(Exchange.FILE_NAME_ONLY, file.getName());
    InputStream targetStream = new FileInputStream(file);
    //send stream as body and list of headers to direct 
    producer.sendBodyAndHeaders(targetStream, headers);
  }
}
```

**Your Camel route**

```
@Component
public class FileUploadRoute extends RouteBuilder {
  @Override
  public void configure() throws Exception {
    //Manage camel exception in a dedicated processor
    onException(Exception.class).process(exceptionProcessor).log("error :: ${exception}");
  
    from(CAMEL_DIRECT_UPLOAD)
    .log("file copy to ftp '${header.CamelFileNameOnly}' in  process")
    .toD("file:/mnt?fileName=${header.CamelFileNameOnly}&delete=false")
    .log("copy done");
  }
}
```